Are there any downsides for "Rapid Release" schedule in Google Workspace?
Most features in Google Workspace are released first for Rapid Release domains. Is there any downside to choosing Rapid Release for our corporate domain?

Paraphrased: What is the downside for an organization when it turns down additional time made available to assess the impact of upcoming application changes?
If your organization is not one that's likely to take advantage of a delayed implementation schedule, the loss of the extra time shouldn't have a material downside over and above what's inherent in the current approach.
If, however, your organization is one that actively manages change, removing the delay between the initial release and the full corporate rollout of new features would eliminate the window in which to assess new functionality to mitigate any negative impact.
An organization that doesn't manage change embraces similar downside risks regardless of whether it uses one release schedule or the other. It is of course possible, but unlikely, that a serious bug will be identified and fixed between the two release dates which could be considered a small upside to the regular schedule, and which you can balance off against the equally minimal upside of your users getting new features slightly faster through rapid deployment.

Scheduled Release (default setting)
- Your users get new features at least 1 week after they’re released to Rapid Release domains. This gives you more time to prepare your organization for changes.

And also,

Tip for large organizations:
Select the Scheduled Release track for your production account. Then, set up Rapid Release on a separate Google Workspace account under a different domain, which allows you to try new features before they’re available to your users.


Thanks, this was enough for me to convince IT to switch our domain's release channel


Is there any downside to choosing Rapid Release for our corporate domain?

Along with features you get bugs.
